# Trying to return a result without creating a new variable

Tags: elixir

Is there any way to simplify this code:

```
def test do
    var1 = func1()
    |> func2()
    |> func3()

    var2 = if var1 == nil do
      var1
    else
      func4(var1)
    end

    func5(var2)
end
```

I want to avoid creating var2 and return result in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the return value of `if` directly to `func5`:

```
if var1 == nil do
  var1
else
  func4(var1)
end
|> func5()
```

Answer (score 5):

While the answer by Dogbert is absolutely correct, I would like to show a couple of tricks one might use here to completely eliminate intermediate local variables.

#### pattern matching instead of `if`

```
def test do
    func1()
    |> func2()
    |> func3()
    |> fn
      nil -> nil
      var -> func4(var)
    end.() # ⇐ call the anonymous function inplace
    |> func5()
end
```

#### chaining `if`

This approach won’t work in this case, since `func4` requires the chained variable to be passed in as a parameter, but in general case `if` might be chained as well:

```
def test do
    func1()
    |> func2()
    |> func3()
    |> if(do: nil, else: func4())
    |> func5()
end
```

The above has a side effect and is not 100% equiv to `== nil`, since `false` is also `falsey`, but the elegance of the example made me think it worth it to mention.

Comment: The first one doesn't compile: `** (ArgumentError) cannot pipe ... into an anonymous function without calling the function; use something like (fn ... end).() or define the anonymous function as a regular private function`.

Answer (score 1):

Another idiomatic solution is to use pattern matching on function arguments. Doing this on func4 (or on a wrapper for func4) would for instance avoid any intermediate variable:

```
def test do
    func1()
    |> func2()
    |> func3()
    |> func4()
    |> func5()
end

def func4(nil), do: nil
def func4(arg) do 
  # whatever you had in func4
end
```